# JSP - Not able to maintain session between http page and https page

Tags: http, session, jsp, tomcat, https

I can't seem to find the one right answer to my problem. I'm being overwhelmed with information I'm finding on the internet, and I have no idea what I should do.

***My setup is as follows :*** Apache server (front end), Tomcat 6.0 (back end), RapidSSL certificate is on the Apache server, my site is made up of Java Server Pages.

***The problem :***
I have a few pages that are under https, while the rest of the site pages are under http. 
The login page I have, is under https, and I've noticed that when I login, and redirect to an http page, that the session is not being maintained. Its creating a new one, which results in the user being sent to my 'session expired' page, when really, upon a successful login, they would be redirected to a different page.

***Questions:***
Why is the session not maintained when switched from https to http?

How do I fix this problem? 
I need the session attributes that are created on the http pages, to be present on the https pages, so when the user is then directed to an http page again, the session hasn't been recreated, and the attributes lost.

Please ask me any questions you feel are necessary in order to help me figure this out. I greatly appreciate any help I receive. This issue has become a stumbling block for me, especially since I obviously lack the 'expertise' to figure it out myself.

Answer (score 3):

Allowing the user to use the same session after logging in is a security vulnerability. Tomcat by default does not allow sessions to migrate from SSL to non SSL pages.

You should change your logic so if a user is doing a login, the session is silently updated, and logged in instead of going to the session expired page.

Comment: The best idea I can come up with, is to recreate the session att's that were lost, and do this during the validation of the username/password params, so that the logic of the pages doesn't think that the session has expired. Does that sound logical?

Comment: I tried my idea out - I've noticed that when I login the 1st time, its successful, but when I logout and log back in the 2nd time, in the same session, its acting as it was before, sending me to session expired.   I should also mention that I've made use of response.encodeURL() for every link on my site. I noticed that when I'm on an http page, the http type links have JSESSIONID present, but the https links do not. Is this adding to my problem some how?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you're using "secure cookies" to maintain the session: these cookies don't propagate from HTTPS to HTTP. This is generally a good thing.

You can chose not to do this, but when you transfer a session from HTTPS to HTTP you have to take extra care that you don't allow it to be reused over HTTPS later, as it may have been compromised.

Comment: I don't believe I'm using "secure cookies" only because I haven't configured anything on Tomcat for such. I'm using session attributes, that's pretty much it.

Comment: Secure cookies are probably the default (that would be sensible anyway), see @Byron Whitlock's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a simple reverse proxy to connect to Tomcat? If that's your case, use `mod_proxy_ajp` to use `AJP` to connect Apache HTTP Server to Tomcat Application Server.

Comment: Yes, mod_ajp is in use on my server. It connects/forwards requests for JSP pages to Tomcat...correct?

Comment: `mod_ajp`? Did you mean `mod_proxy_ajp` or `mod_jk`? It's not cleared what the impact of this is regarding the problem between HTTPS and HTTP, even compared with `mod_proxy_http`.

Comment: I'm sorry, yes, it is mod_jk, not mod_ajp, my apologies.

Comment: @Bruno: yes, I meant `mod_proxy_ajp`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, where some parts of the site are https, and some are http. I've found that with Tomcat, session cookies created over http carry over to https no problem, however session cookies created over https are lost when moving to http.

One solution I have found maintaining a session as the user travels the site, is to bounce the user around when they first arrive. I created a RequestFilter with the following code:

```
if (request.isSecure() && session.isNew()) { // session cookie created over ssl
    try { session.invalidate(); }
    catch (Exception e) { /* handle error */ }
    String url = request.getRequestURI().replaceFirst("https", "http");
    response.sendRedirect(url);
}
else if (!request.isSecure()) {
    String url = request.getRequestURI().replaceFirst("http", "https");
    response.sendRedirect(url);
}
```

This forces new sessions to non SSL to create a lasting session cookie, and then once a session exists, the user forwarded back to secure request. This results in the session staying alive.

Or here's an options that involves less bouncing around, just overwrite the session cookie with one that isn't secure:

```
if (request.isSecure() && session.isNew()) {
    Cookie c = new Cookie("JSESSIONID", request.getSession().getId());
    c.setSecure(false);
    response.addCookie(c);
}
```